# Different boundary conditions

Tags: finite-element-method, acegen

I have a problem regarding the definition of multiple boundary conditions in AceFEM.
I am dealing with coupled problem simulations (displacement and magnetic potential) and therefore I have to apply different boundary conditions simultaneously.
For some analyses, the potential is varied by a load factor. This works well.
Now I have the problem, that I want to apply the load factor to the potential but I also want to apply a constant (non-zero) displacement simultaneously.

Is there a way that the load factor only affects the potential and the displacement remains constant?

Thank you in advances,

Max

Comment: You need to include an example and the code you have so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should prescribe displacements boundary conditions with the command
SMTAddInitialBoundary[..., "EssentialBoundary"->True]
Prescribed in this way BC will not be scaled with the load factor.